# Show that $9|2^{2n+1}+2^{4n+1}-4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that $9|2^{2n+1}+2^{4n+1}-4$ ( n is a positive integer):
>   1-Using induction
>   2-Don't use induction

I have noticed that $2^m \equiv 2^{m+6} \pmod 9 $ but couldn't use it to solve the problem!

Comment: You can use binomial theorem for the 2nd part since $2 =3 -1$

Comment: There are many similar questions on MSE, e.g. [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443882/how-to-prove-that-4n-3n-1-is-divisible-by-9), or [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444222/prove-that-9-mid-4n15n-1-for-all-n-in-mathbb-n).

Comment: We also have $36\mid 2^{2n+1}+2^{4n+1}-4$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$, $n\ge 0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's true for all non-negative integers $n$.

Without induction:

$9\mid 2^{2n+1}+2^{4n+1}-4$ is equivalent to $$9\mid 2\cdot 2^{2n+1}+\left(2^{2n+1}\right)^2-8$$

$$=\left(2^{2n+1}+1\right)^2-9$$

I.e. $9=3^2\mid \left(2^{2n+1}+1\right)^2$, i.e. $3\mid 2^{2n+1}+1$, which is true,

because $2^{2n+1}\equiv (-1)^{2n+1}\equiv -1\pmod{3}$, because $2n+1$ is odd for all $n\in\mathbb Z$, $n\ge 0$.

---

With induction:

Clearly $9\mid 2^{2\cdot 0+1}+2^{4\cdot 0+1}-4=0$.

If $9\mid 2^{2n+1}+2^{4n+1}-4$, then

$$9\mid 2^{2(n+1)+1}+2^{4(n+1)+1}-4$$

$$=\left(2^{2n+1}+2^{4n+1}-4\right)+3\left(2^{2n+1}+5\cdot 2^{4n+1}\right)$$

because $$2^{2n+1}+5\cdot 2^{4n+1}\pmod{3}$$

$$\equiv (-1)^{2n+1}-(-1)^{4n+1}\pmod{3}$$

$$\equiv -1-(-1)\equiv 0\pmod{3}$$

Comment: This is so compact and nice....+1

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $a_n = 2^{2n+1}+2^{4n+1}-4$, then $a_n=20a_{n-1}-64a_{n-2}-180$

Answer (score 2):

$2^{2n+1}+2^{4n+1}-4 = f(2^{2n})$ for $f(x)=2x^2+2x-4=2(x-1)(x+2)$.

Now $2^{2n} \bmod 9$ is $1,4,7,1,4,7,\dots$ and

$f(1) \equiv 0 \bmod 9$

$f(4) = 36 \equiv 0 \bmod 9$

$f(7) \equiv 0 \bmod 9$

So $f(2^{2n}) \equiv 0 \bmod 9$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

$2(4^{\large 2n}+4^{\large n}-2) \,=\, 2\,(\overbrace{(\color{#c00}{4^{\large n}\!-1})^{\large 2}}^{\Large (\color{#c00}{3k})^{\Large 2}}\!+\overbrace{3(\color{#c00}{4^{\large n}\!-1}))}^{\Large 3\,(\color{#c00}{3k})\ \ \ }\,$ is divisible by $\,9\,$ since $\,\color{#c00}{3\mid 4^{\large n}-1}\,$ (easily provable either by congruence arithmetic, the factor theorem, the binomial theorem, or induction).

Answer (score 1):

$2x^2+2x-4=2(x^2+x-2)=2(x+2)(x-1)=2(x-1+3)(x-1)$ so, for $x=2^{2n}=4^n$,
$$
2^{2n+1}+2^{4n+1}-4=2(4^n-1+3)(4^n-1)
$$
and you just need to show that $3\mid 4^n-1$.

### No induction

Since $4\equiv1\pmod{3}$, the statement is proved.

### With induction

The base case is obvious. If $4^n-1=3k$ with $k$ integer,
$$
4^{n+1}-1=4\cdot 4^n-1=4(3k+1)=12k+4-1=3(4k+1)
$$

Comment: Or notice that $4^n-1=(4-1)\left(4^{n-1}+4^{n-2}+\cdots+4^0\right)$

or more generally if $n\in\mathbb Z$, $n\ge 2$, then $$a^n-b^n=(a-b)\left(a^{n-1}b^0+a^{n-2}b^1+\cdots+a^0 b^{n-1}\right)$$

Comment: Bravo, nice and elegant technique! +1